# Did the “too-localized” vote option disappear?

Tags: support, too-localized, 10k-tools

Isn’t it possible anymore to vote as “too-localized” or am I overlooking something ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The closing reasons were [redefined a little while ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154): one of the big changes was removal of 'too localized' (TL). This created a *lot* of discussion, but the network staff ('Powers') are sticking to it. The logic is something like this: TL was far from the most common close reason, and was used for issues well beyond what it was originally intended for, which was really *localized* issues that *no-one else would ever see*. It's that last bit that's important: for example, we (usually) haven't answered questions that come down to 'my installation is messed up', but that applies to more than one person. Thus the message from above is that these things are off-topic, in the sense that if a site doesn't answer questions on X then they are closed for scope reasons even if X seems to be a *prima facia* fit for the site.

Note that questions closed with a no answer and a low number of votes and views are likely to be removed by the 'garbage collector' system. That applies whether closed as the old TL or using off topic. So in the longer term it probably makes little odds.