# questions answered by pointing out simple typos

Tags: discussion

This comment by @Gernot in response to

[Solved by comment -> how to flag](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7258/solved-by-comment-how-to-flag)

> Not all questions are worth an answer or to be preserved, but
>   nevertheless should be solved. Just think of the syntactic errors,
>   like missing braces, where the solution will help no one else. Or
>   sometimes the OP reports him/herself to have solved the problem,
>   somehow. What's wrong is to give as reason "because solved in
>   comments". I fully agree that this is no reason. Instead it should be
>   something like "syntactic error" or "unclear". Or, as Clemens points
>   out, there should be a real answer, if there is any chance that
>   someone else with the same problem will stumble across the post. –
>   gernot yesterday

prompts this question from me:

If the question is really a one-off typo that no one else will encounter (or find this question if they do) should we answer (perhaps in a comment) and suggest that the OP delete the question when satisfied with the answer? Perhaps if the OP is a newbie, thank him/her for asking.

Comment: I think it would be appropriate. Answering, thanking for posting here and asking to delete the question sounds like a good sequence. Probably there will also some reviewer who can't wait and will close it as off-topic, but your version would be friendly ;)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with closing a question *What is wrong with tableofcotnents?* Leave a comment that there are infinite questions of that type and we can't keep them all. The user will be happy the issue is fixed.

Comment: Helping the user should be highest priority. If a question gets closed or deleted (or stays unanswered for years) is just for the statistics of the site and less important.

Comment: IIRC typos are off-topic by convention.

Comment: IMO there is no such thing as “a one-off typo that no one else will encounter”. If one person can make a typo, another person can make the same one too; the possibility exists. So IMO they should be treated as actual questions and answered (however trivial the answer); it may help someone else in future.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR As there is an infinite amount of ways to misspell `\tableofcontents` .... I don't see the point. Add a comment pointing out where exactly the typo is. Maybe we should have a Q/A explaining what `undefined control sequesnce` means.

Comment: People shuold never maek tpyos...